# Simular enter jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Necesito simular un enter en jquery tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$('').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
```

Pero este se realiza sobre un elemento , con un id o clase , yo necesito generar el enter automaticamente sin necesidad de referenciar a un elemento espero explicarme bien estoy a atento a sus respuestas.

Comment: El enter es para algo, osea debe ir a algún lado o no?

Comment: ¿Y si referencias el documento? `$(document)`

Answer (score 3):

Usa $('body') como selector, te dejo un ejemplo

```
//Cuando se presione enter
$('body').keypress(function (e) {
    if(e.which == 13){
        alert('ok');
    }
});

//Simula que se presiona la tecla enter 
$('body').trigger({
    type: 'keypress',
    which: 13
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a ver si esto te puede ayudar... suerte.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', function() {
        $(document).trigger($.Event('keypress', { keycode: 13 }));
    });
});
```